# React with TypeScript - Firebase database returns 400 on PUT-method with Axios

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I am working on a fairly simple todo app. But not without problems.

I am trying to make a PUT request to an Google Firebase realtime database.

In my create request I create an autogenerated ID that I am using for the PUT reguest also.

However, when I try to execute the function it returns 400-Bad reguest.

Something like this previously happend before with my Delete function. I could not use the Id, but when deleting everything (same function but without the Id in the url) it works just fine.

Here is some code

```
 export const MarkAsDone = async (id: number) => {
  // const {id}: any = useParams();
  try {
    await axios.put(`${UrlTodo}/${id}.json`);
    window.location.reload();
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
}};

export const DeleteAll = async () => {
    try {
        await axios.delete(`${UrlTodo}.json`);
        window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
};
```

And here is some code from the view side

```
    <td>
       <Button onClick={() => MarkAsDone(todo.id)} className={todo.isComplete ? "d-none" : "btn btn-outline-primary"}>Mark as done</Button>
   </td>
    
    <Button onClick={() => DeleteAll()} className="btn btn-outline-danger">Remove All</Button>
```

The `DeleteAll()` function works. But when trying to delete 1 single object it does not work and it would return a 400, so I guess there might be something weird when trying to access a specific object by ID.

The `MarkAsDone()` does not work and returns a 400.

Also, when using Firebase realtime database, you need to add `.json` at the end of every URL. Just to make things clear about that :)

If anyone has any idea, please let me know!

Thanks!

Edit:
I tried passing in data with a model into the PUT-request
I added this

```
 export interface updateTodoModel {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    isComplete: boolean = true;
}
```

it is the same data that I am working with, but the only update I want is to make the isComplete true with a press of a button.

I updated the `MarkAsDone()` function like this

```
export const MarkAsDone = async (id: number, todo: updateTodoModel) => {
  // const {id}: any = useParams();
  try {
    await axios.put(`${UrlTodo}/${id}.json`, todo);
    window.location.reload();
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
}};
```

Still the same problem though. How could this be done?

Comment: You aren't passing any data to update in the put request?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I updated the code a bit and updated my question accordingly, if you would like to check it out as well.

I tried passing data to the put request but it did not work, I might be doing it wrong though. Any ideas?